# Query in insert statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript

I have the following VB statement for inserting text data to a SQL 2008 DB. How can I check if sValueList already exists in sFieldNameList column while doing the insert?

```
sInsertStatement = "INSERT " & sTableName 
                   & "(" & sFieldNameList & ") VALUES(" 
                   & Mid(sValueList , 3) & ")"
```

Comment: Is it the SQL or VBScript you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM " & sTableName * " 
                WHERE " & sFieldNameList & " = " & sValueList & ") 
 BEGIN
    "INSERT " & sTableName 
              & "(" & sFieldNameList & ") VALUES(" 
              & Mid(sValueList , 3) & ")"  
 END
```

(this needs to be adapted to a VBScript syntax though!)

Comment: I guess im lost on one thing which maybe I should not be, but tis been a while. in teh if statement, do i execute the objConn.execute as so?
    IF NOT EXISTS (objConn.execute "SELECT LN FROM " & sTableName * " WHERE LN = " & sValueList(0) & ")

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You would pass the entire SQL statement as a single argument to objConn.execute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do either UPDATE or INSERT? What you need is an UPSERT command. Basically you need a WHERE clause like:

```
where not exists (select 1 from mytable where col2='myId').
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991198/dynamic-upsert-in-postgresql) how postgres do it.

sql2008 does not have same functionality but [check this blog](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131) (end of page) where they do:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
merge into mytable as Target
using mytable2 as Source
on Target.id=Source.id
when matched then 
update set Target.name=Source.name,
Target.Salary = Source.Salary
when not matched then
insert (id,name,salary) values (Source.id,Source.name,Source.Salary);
```